# Split and Copy Table

Tags: sql-server, select, insert, copy

hello following is the Problem; let me know if there is any way to solve it...

Problem : need to copy a table T1 to another table T2. 
But T1.Col2 should be split as T2.Col2 and T3.Col3 while copying.

here is the query i used;

```
Insert INTO T2 (Col1,Col2)
SELECT Col1, 
    substring(
        CAST(Col2 AS varchar(30)), 
        1, 
        patindex('% %', CAST(Col2 AS varchar(30)))-1
    ), 
    substring(
        CAST(Col2 AS varchar(30)), 
        patindex('% %', Len(CAST(Col2 AS varchar(30))))+1,
        Len(Col2)
    )

from T1
```

I am getting the following error :

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would suggest that you try building this one field at a time. Get it working for one field. Then add another field. Your problem is probably punctuation -- too many or not enough parentheses. You will find the problem more easily if you develop the code step by step.

Comment: Have applied a bunch of indenting, which, I think makes the error easier to spot!

Comment: @DOK : Thanks, corrected the punctuations, got a new error. refer above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer,

```
INSERT INTO T2 
           (T2COL1
           ,T2COL2 
           ,T2COL3) 
SELECT T1COL1 
      ,Convert(date, CONVERT(nvarchar(20), T1COL2, 101)) 
      ,convert(time(7), CONVERT(nvarchar(20), T1COL2, 108)) 
FROM T1
```

We can use conversion code while dealing with Date and Time to ease job. i referred the following link;

http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SQLDateTimeFormats.aspx

Thanks for all. :)

Answer (score 3):

You are short 2 close parens on your select and you are missing the third column name in your insert into.

```
Insert INTO T2 (Col1,Col2,Col3)
SELECT Col1, 
    substring(CAST(Col2 AS varchar(30)), 1, patindex('% %', CAST(Col2 AS varchar(30)))-1), 
    substring(CAST(Col2 AS varchar(30)), patindex('% %', Len(CAST(Col2 AS varchar(30))))
from T1
```

Comment: +1 good spot on the missing cols (completely missed that in a malaize of brackets)

Answer (score 1):

As I've now indented it, you're missing bracket on the second section with the patindex statement (because you added a `len(` probably:

```
        1          2    3               4  432...
patindex('% %', Len(CAST(Col2 AS varchar(30)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this and let us know if it works

```
Insert INTO T2 (Col1,Col2, Col3)
SELECT Col1, 
substring(CAST(Col2 AS varchar(30)), 1, patindex('% %', CAST(Col2 AS varchar(30)))-1), 
substring(CAST(Col2 AS varchar(30)), patindex('% %', Len(CAST(Col2 AS varchar(30)))))
from T1
```

It looks like you were missing one of the columns